# Repeater ItemCommand doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm having trouble in a Repeater in webform where OnItemCommand event is not working. He should be fired when I click the Linkbutton.

Codigo aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterImagens" runat="server" 
        OnItemCommand="repeaterImagens_ItemCommand" 
        OnItemDataBound="repeaterImagens_ItemDataBound">
       <ItemTemplate>

...

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbExcluir" runat="server"
                        CommandName="excluir"
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((String)Container.DataItem) %>" 
                        OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?'));">
                </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind C#

```
protected void repeaterImagens_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName.Equals("excluir"))
    {
           ExcluirArquivo(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     }
}
```

Tested in debug mode, clicking the Linkbutton nothing happens, not even to call the ItemCommand event

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `OnClientClick` attribtue from the `LinkButton`?

Comment: I remove the OnCLientCLick, and still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to handle linkbutton client confirmation in [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
 protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
    LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("lbExcluir") as LinkButton;

    if (lb != null) {
       lb.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?')";
     }
 }
```

Comment: during debug, it seems that OnItemCommand event does not work. The event is not called, and the page load occurs.

Comment: See the reference link in the post. It will be helpful.